# How execute commands as another user during provisioning on Vagrant?

Tags: linux, vagrant, root, sudo, vagrant-provision

`Vagrant` executes my scripts as `root` during provision. But I would like to execute, during the provisioning time, some commands as another user.
This is how I'm doing at the moment:

```
  su - devops -c "git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv"
  su - devops -c "echo 'export PATH=\"$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH\"' >> ~/.bash_profile"
  su - devops -c "echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile"
  su - devops -c "git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build"
  su - devops -c "echo 'export PATH=\"$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH\"' >> ~/.bash_profile"
  su - devops -c "source ~/.bash_profile"
```

But I would like to make this nicer, something like this:

```
#become devops user here

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# back to the root user here
```

Is this possible ? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have the script inline with the rest you can use a command sequence such as the following.

```
sudo -u devops /bin/sh <<\DEVOPS_BLOCK
# Become devops user here
id
whoami
# Back to the root user here
DEVOPS_BLOCK
```

Answer (score 5):

when running the provisioning, its true that vagrant will run as root by default, you can change this behavior by making the provision as

```
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false blablabla
```

vagrant will then use the user defined as `config.ssh.username`, if its not set, its vagrant user by default

If you have multiple users on your system and still want to use another user, what I would do is to write a script and execute the script as `su -l newuser -c "path to shell script"`

Comment: hadn't seen the `privileged: false` setting, thanks for this.